# jQuery click not doing anything?

Tags: jquery, dom

The following code is supposed to, on click of `<span class="edit_submit"></span>`, get the contents of the `textarea` and send it, via POST, to `edited_page.php`, and then display the contents of `edited_page.php`. At the moment, I don't believe the function is even running. Any ideas?

[Fiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/G2M4X/)

```
$('.edit_submit').on('click', function () {
                $parent = $(this).parent()
                $textarea = $(this).siblings(".el-rte").child(".workzone").child("textarea");
                $text = $textarea.val();
                $id = $textarea.attr('id');
                $parent.html("images/load.jpg").load("edited_page.php", {location: $id, content: $text, page: "<?php echo $page; ?>"});
            });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="el-rte">
        <div class="workzone" style="height: 400px;">
            <textarea id="main" class="edit_area" style="display: none; height: 400px;" name="main">
                &lt;b&gt;Hello. &lt;/b&gt;&lt;i&gt;This is sam &lt;/i&gt;&lt;u&gt;Testing this website&nbsp;&lt;/u&gt;
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="edit_submit" style="background:black;">Save Edit</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put alerts or console.log within your function to see if it is getting in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2M4X/2/)... there is no `child()` method in jquery i used `children()`... and fixed issues that was there in your fiddle

```
$('.edit_submit').on('click', function () {
           $parent = $(this).parent()
           $textarea = $(this).siblings(".el-rte").children(".workzone").children("textarea");
           $text = $textarea.val();
           $id = $textarea.attr('id');
           alert($id);
           $parent.html("images/load.jpg").load("edited_page.php", {location: $id, content: $text, page: "<?php echo $page; ?>"});
        });
```

**AND INSTEAD OF GOING THROUGH CHILDREN AND SIBLINGS**..you can just use `find()`

```
$textarea = $parent.find('textarea');
```

**updated**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2M4X/6/)

Comment: I seriously just picked up jQuery today and am just modifying some stuff I had before. Thanks for the tip about find().

Comment: I still can't get my local version to work. If I (in a previous jQuery function) append the `textarea` and the `.edit_submit` `<span>` to `<div id="main">` (as opposed to being originally within the document), will the new function still be able to find it, or does it only look for `textarea` and `.edit_submit` when the document is ready?

Comment: can you provide me with a fiddle.. i got little confused here...and yesa i noticed you have to IDs with a same name.. that is invalid...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/G2M4X/5/. I've tried to comment everything so it's clear.

Comment: ok here is the fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/G2M4X/6/... checkout the comments too....

Answer (score 1):

You need to make below changes.

```
<div id="main"> 
<textarea id="main">
```

ID for **DOM MUST BE UNIQUE**

You have same id for more than one DOM i think that is the issue.

**OR**

```
$textarea = $(this).prev(".el-rte").find(".workzone textarea");
console.log($textarea);
```

Comment: The top two ($id and $text) are jQuery variables. The last one is a PHP variable.

Comment: ohhh my bad i didn't notice it...sorry.

Comment: Fixed that > didn't even realise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('.edit_submit').click( function () {
                $parent = $(this).parent()
                $textarea = $(this).siblings(".el-rte").child(".workzone").child("textarea");
                $text = $textarea.val();
                $id = $textarea.attr('id');
                $parent.html("images/load.jpg").load("edited_page.php", {location: $id, content: $text, page: "<?php echo $page; ?>"});
            });
```

Comment: this won't.. there is no `child()` method in jquery as far as i knowq

Answer (score 0):

```
$textarea = $(this).siblings(".el-rte").child(".workzone").child("textarea");
```

change to

```
$textarea = $(this).siblings(".el-rte").children(".workzone").children("textarea");
```

and code into `document ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.edit_submit').on('click', function () {
        $parent = $(this).parent()
        $textarea = $(this).siblings(".el-rte").children(".workzone").children("textarea");
        $text = $textarea.val();
        $id = $textarea.attr('id');
        $parent.html("images/load.jpg").load("edited_page.php", {location: $id, content: $text, page: "<?php echo $page; ?>"});
    });
})
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jikeytang/G2M4X/3/)